# Highlight empty textbox from textbox array in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, textbox, highlight

my question is

i have created a textbox array of names in codeigniter
on form submission the controller sends back to the same view when it finds an empty textbox.

error can be displayed by form_error(textbox[]).
my question is that i want to highlight only empty textboxes from textbox array

```
    <form action="" id="frmAssessmentDetail" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <table width="476" style="margin-top:20px" >
       <tr>
          <td>
             <input type="text" name="names[]" value="" id="names[]" />
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: use jquery to check whether it is empty.. then add a css class to it..